# Is it possible to configure mongoDB inside meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to disable journaling or adding the smallfiles parameter to mongo.
The reason behind this is that I have 1.5 gigs free disk space, and mongodb allocates 1.2 from that. I've read that it can be disabled, or the file size can be amended, but I haven't found where to configure it if it's running inside the meteor framework.

Answer (score 1):

That issue may help you : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/15

And this is quite simple when you application is deployed/builded since the meteor project and mongodb are well separated.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to do this, but I am unable to locate `mongo_runner.js`. I am using a VM in Koding, if that's any help.

Comment: You can try to edit the file ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.q4knzy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-mongo.js
 and add args.push("--nojournal") line 28, but I think you will need to recompile this package after the edition. I did not test but I think it will work.
On an other hand, did you tried to run meteor --reset ? It remove the current database and that's maybe enought for you.